# How to store photos in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

Can anybody tell me how to store photos (jpg, png etc) files in cassandra ?
Any small example would give me quick start.

Comment: I am not looking for any performance here. My image will definitely not be more than 100 MB. I just want a simple mechanisum to store and retrieve images from Cassandra.
I am using hector client to retrieve other types of data from Cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

"Manually split files into chunks of whatever size you are comfortable with". (from [CassandraLimitations](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations))

Eg. use the file name as the row key and have the chunks as columns.

Answer (score 0):

Using Asytanax Client (Netflix) you can store large files. Take a look at the link below -
https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Chunked-Object-Store

You can specify the chunk size that the files would be split into.